# Move Directory across SVN repository using Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to move a sub directory from one directory to another, given that both are inside the same SVN repository? I am using tortoise SVN.

Comment: You can find more thorough answer [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/most-forgotten-feature)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Select the folder/files that you want to move, then RIGHT-CLICK them and drag them to where you want to move them.  A menu will come up with an option "**SVN Move versioned files here**"

As clarified by [phenry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264571/move-directory-across-svn-repository-using-tortoise-svn/1894533#1894533), the destination folder must be recognized as an SVN folder.  The folder should already be committed to the repository or you can choose Add to set it to be added.

If the destination folder isn't part of an SVN repository, use the SVN Export command after your right-click and drag to copy the files to any destination folder.

Comment: Wow.  Didn't know that.  TortoiseSVN was beginning to tick me off with that.

Comment: Excellent.  What does move and rename do?

Comment: I believe that move and rename bring up a dialog prompting you for the new name or location.  You must use "Rename" to keep the version history of a file.  Move is the same as dragging and dropping and select the "Move versioned files here"

Comment: holy crap..i never knew i could do that. Thanks a whole bunch!

Comment: Holy crap that's amazing...they should just have that on the front page.

Answer (score 24):

Note that [Chris Thompson's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264571/move-directory-across-svn-repository-using-tortoise-svn/264576#264576) only works if **both directories are already recognized by TortoiseSVN**. If you create a new folder in Explorer and try to move a file to it from an existing folder, you won't get the TortoiseSVN contextual menu items. After you create the new folder, you have to do either a **Commit** action (which creates a new version number) or an **Add** action (which doesn't), so TortoiseSVN knows about the new folder, and then you'll get the option to move the items in SVN. More [here](http://www.modhul.com/2008/11/14/moving-directories-in-a-svn-repository-using-tortoise-svn/).

Comment: I'm one of those who missed this part. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 10):

Or in the Repository Browser, you can just drag the file/folder and drop into the desired folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have renamed the parent folder before moving, you would see a "Cross/Not allowed" sign when moving.

The workaround is to first move the child and then only re-name the parent (undo if you already renamed the parent).