# Change SVN Path Entirely

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

We have an SVN at `http:/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1111/svn/AB/` - and the first two folders of the SVN are like `http:/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1111/svn/AB/abc/filefolder/`

The problem is we want to move the entire svn to get rid of `/abc/filefolder/` as the entire project sits under `/abc/filefolder/` [created long ago and never bothered to change] (que stupid yes yes)

How would we could about fixing this so we dont loose logs etc? We dont want to have to export and create a new svn, since then we lose all our log files. But we want to "move" the svn root so for example it becomes:

```
From: http:/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1111/svn/AB/abc/filefolder/documents/
To: http:/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1111/svn/AB/documents/
```

Any help appreciated? [ps - yes had to remove `http://` due to link restriction]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about you just move the folders you want at the top level, working on the repository, for example:

```
svn move http:/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1111/svn/AB/abc/filefolder/documents/ http:/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1111/svn/AB/
```

Back up your repository beforehand, of course.

Comment: hi - so is this like "relocate" using tortisesvn ?

Comment: @Tom: No. It's the way to move folders within an SVN repo. It preserves the history etc.

Comment: @sbi thx - can this be achieved via TortiseSVN or only via command line?

Comment: For Tortoise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264571/move-directory-across-svn-repository-using-tortoise-svn